# bootstrap - using visible-phone to change CSS not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

CSS nob looking at bootstrap...

I assumed classes like .visible-phone, .visible-desktop, etc... were applied to the body tag.  Looking in firebug that doesn't appear to be the case.

What I'm trying to do is change CSS settings based on .visible-xxxx,  for example:

```
.ugly-color { color: red; }

.visible-desktop .ugly-color { color: green; }

<div class="visible-desktop">I see this text</div>

<div class="ugly-color">Why is this red and not green</div>
```

Does anyone know where the .visible-desktop is applied?  as if it was the body tag, then ugly-color would be inside .visible-desktop

All input appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space between selectors in CSS means the second is inside the first. So your CSS rule that selects `.visible-desktop .ugly-color` will only trigger when the `.ugly-color` is inside `.visible-desktop`. To select those with both classes, remove the space:

```
.visible-desktop.ugly-color { color: green; }
```

[This W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) details CSS selector syntax pretty well, just in case you need some more options.

Answer (score 1):

Because you .visible-desktop .ugly-color means that there are two elements in each other, like this it works:

```
.ugly-color {color: red;}

.visible-desktop .ugly-color {color: green;}


<div class="visible-desktop">I see this text</div>

<div class="ugly-color">This is red</div>

 <div class="visible-desktop">
        <div class="ugly-color">
            why is red, and not green
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
.ugly-color {color: red;}

.visible-desktop + .ugly-color {color: green;}
```